# What is `softtabstop` used for?

Tags: vimrc, tab-characters

I've been aware of these tab related settings in Vim:

- `ts`
- `sw`
- `expandtab`
- `smarttab`
- `sts`

My normal setting is `set ts=4 sw=4 expandtab smarttab`.

But according to [`sts` documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27sts%27), if `expandtab` is not set, it will try to use a combination of spaces and tabs to make up of the desired number of blanks for a tab size.

I can't really think of a useful scenario for this setting: Why would someone wants to have a fixed number of tabs and spaces that may just mess things up? The only advantage of doing this that I can think of is to reduce the number of characters and thus reduce the file size, which seems weird to me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As the `softtabstop` documention mentions, it's useful if you want to keep the default tab stop size of 8, but edit a file as if the tab stop size was some other value. For example, if you wanted an indentation level of 4 while editing code, but some comments had tab-indented text such as a table that depended on a tab stop of 8, you could set `sts` to `4`.

One difference I notice between your tab settings (`set ts=4 sw=4 expandtab smarttab`) and the use of `sts` (e.g. `set ts=8 sts=4`) is when backspacing over spaces in the middle of a line of text. For example, consider the following line of text, where `·` indicates a space:

```
some·text·······more·text
```

In insert mode, move the cursor just before the `m` of `more text`. With your settings, pressing Backspace deletes a single space. But while using `sts=4`, Backspace deletes all the way to the previous tab stop, as it would behave if the spaces were a tab character instead.

You can set `sts=4` in addition to your settings and get the mid-line backspace behavior while not mixing tabs and spaces. Tabs will be expanded to four spaces, but you can backspace over a range of spaces in the middle of a line.

Answer (score 30):

The value of `'softtabstop'` equals how many columns (=spaces) the cursor moves right when you press `<Tab>`, and how many columns it moves left when you press `<BS>` (backspace) to erase a tab.

Thus, if `'tabstop'` is 8, and `'softtabstop'` is 4, all displayed tabs are 8 columns wide, but every press of the `<Tab>` key just gets you half a tab (=4 spaces) forward at a time:

[image: softtabstop=4]

(red: tabs, green: spaces)

As you can see, whenever the spaces add up to the size of `'tabstop'`, they are turned into a single tab character. (This can be prevented by setting `'expandtab'`.)

A value of `0` disables `'softtabstop'`, so pressing `<Tab>` then gets you a regular tab forward:

[image: softtabstop=0]

Finally, a negative value means fall back to the value of `'shiftwidth'`. Therefore, the cursor here advances two spaces at a time:

[image: softtabstop=-1]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It might be worth sharing what you did to get the highlights/characters

Comment: Please do share :)  I know it's `set list` to show the whitespace, but I'd love to know how to set the symbols themselves to get those coloured arrows!

Answer (score 7):

See the example below,

```
// Start vim without loading your vimrc. set only tabstop=8 softtabstop=4.
// This makes <Tab> in insert mode equals to 4 <Space> length at max.

// In insert mode, type 12, one <Tab>, 5. We get insertion below,
12··5
// Quit insert mode. Move cursor back, we find 2 <Space> inserted.

// In insert mode, type 12, two <Tab>, 9. We get insertion below,
12······9
// Quit insert mode. Move cursor back, you find a <Tab> inserted.

// In insert mode, type 12, three <Tab>, 3. We get insertion below,
12··········3
// Move the cursor back, you find a <Tab> and 4 <Space> inserted.

// We can even set sotftabstop=12, but this time we only need type one <Tab>, then 3.
12··········3
// Move the cursor back, you find a <Tab> and 4 <Sapce> inserted.
```

So `tabstop` is about how wide a `Tab` is defined, while `softtabstop` is about how far cursor moves while **typing** `Tab`. When they are not set to be the same value, it means that if you hit the `Tab` keystroke, it does not imply trivially a `Tab`character. In whatever cases, It is vim who decide once you quit insert mode. Vim will first try to match the insertion by as many `tabstop` as it can; if at last it cannot make a full `tabstop`, vim simply compensates by `Space`.

To speak a little bit more, if you set `expandtab`, it is equal to say to vim:

> Please do not bother to calculate how many `Tab` and `Sapce` is needed. Simply insert `Space`.

Comment: @Herb Wolfe I wish my answer can help PO figure out what happens when unusual setting is made like`:set st=7 sts=13`. As vim is not only designed for coding, but originally for text editing.

Comment: Use `vim --clean` to start vim without loading your vimrc.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer:

For example, it's extremly useful for programming, especially in Python, in which tabulation is crucial. 
When you press backspace with sts=4, it will untab the line, not delete a single space character.