# The tab adds 8 spaces even though `set tabstop?` returns 4

Tags: tab-characters

For some reasons when I'm editing my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, it adds 8 spaces even though I set `set tabstop=4` on the file. Actually, `:verbose set tabstop` returns 4, so it should be 4 spaces.

I already read the questions [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/vim-displaying-incorrect-indentation) and [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13442/files-with-tabs-are-length-8-even-with-set-tabstop-4-in-vimrc), and strangely, in Python I have no problem on adding 4 spaces.

What is causing the problem? How can I investigate the problem further and fix it up?

Comment: It shouldn't be inserting 4 spaces it should be adding a `Tab`. That is, unless you have some other settings with non-default values...particularaly `'expandtabs'`. And what do you have for `'softtabstop'`, `'shiftwidth'`, `'cpoptions'` while we're at it? This is only for `*.vim` files? Only when you simply hit Tab in Insert mode or other circumstances (e.g. autoindent scenarios)?

Comment: Doesn't your init.vim file have a mode line? It's a comment in the file itself, by default in the 5 first or last lines which begin with " vim:" and allow to override some options like tabstop...

Comment: @fievel That's equivalent to `:setlocal` and would show up as the value returned by `:set tabstop` ... OP said that returns 4.

Comment: Oh, and add your value for `'smarttab'`, too @Blaszard.

Comment: @BLayer `softtabstop` is 4, and I found that the `shiftwidth` is set to 8. Setting it to 4 solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: Cool. We'll probably close this question since it does it lend itself to an answer useful to the general vim public.

Comment: @BLayer It seems to me that confusion between `tabstop`, `softtabstop`, and `shiftwidth` is common enough to warrant a question?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate as it doesn't cover `shiftwidth`): [What is `softtabstop` used for?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4244/51) I'm surprised we don't have a question on this already!

Comment: @MartinTournoij Certainly if there's a need for it I wouldn't argue against a q&a for `'shiftwidth'`, `'softtabstop'`, et al. But there are already answers that discuss them, AFAIK. The only way to add value, IMO, is to totally rewrite the question here to ask specifically about the settings. Otherwise, there are no better odds of someone wanting to know about them finding this page than any of the others. (Probably lower odds at this point since the others surely have more votes.) Is this kind of situation that calls for a community q&a? (If there is such a thing.) Otherwise just dup this..?

Comment: BTW, my close vote was based on this criteria: "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." since the resolution came about as a result of my follow up question comments. Anyways, I'm up for whatever best serves the community.

Comment: Looks like [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/495/how-to-replace-tabs-with-spaces?rq=1) could be considered the de-facto FAQ for tabs/spaces settings. (And while we're at it [this one](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces) is a solid external reference.)